# void ** pointer in function argument c++

Tags: c++, function, arguments, void-pointers

How to output variable of wchar_t * from void ** function argument in this situation?

I want to insert value of t in ChangeMe variable by using void**, how to accomplish that?

```
void foo(void **v){ wchar_t *t = L"String is changed!"; *(wchar_t*)v = *t; } 
wchar_t *ChangeMe = L"";
```

Try already (dont work):

```
foo((void**)ChangeMe );
```

Comment: Since this is C++, perhaps you were looking for a template and reference: `template<typename T> void foo(T &t) {t = newValue;}`

Comment: @chris of course that those what you say can help, but specifically now im searching for how to "output" value "String is chaged!" inside of wchar_t *ChangeMe

Comment: If it must be a `wchar_t*` (not sure why you have `void*` then), just kill the template and use a reference as your parameter: `wchar_t *&`. Pass in the variable like you would to any other function and assign to it like you would to any other variable.

Comment: You probably wanted to write `*((wchar_t**)v) = t;` (note that `t`'s value goes out of scope after return though). Don't bother with `void` pointers, write proper c++ code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ -> great this one working, you can post it as answare

Comment: @tonni I did so. But remember I've been warning you. You might be lucky getting away with the string literal.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ -> of course but in this question i want to particularly find out way how to cast "v" to "t"

Comment: `void*` is the pointer convertible to any data pointer. `void**` is just pointer to `void*`.

Comment: @tonni There's also still a little mistake when you're calling `foo()`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably wanted to write

```
*((wchar_t**)v) = t;
```

Note that `t`'s value goes out of scope after return though. This may work in this case, because the literal's address has static storage duration.

Also when passing `ChangeMe` to the function you want to specify its address actually:

```
foo((void**)&ChangeMe);
         // ^
```

Here's the [fully working sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83993e8d20a69208).

---

Don't bother with void pointers; write proper C++ code.